# UImanagedDocument's persistentStore iCloud backup

Tags: core-data, icloud, uimanageddocument, nspersistentstore

Im trying to create backups for core data UIManagedDocument, and store them in iCloud. Its been > 2 months since im trying to do this and i dont understand how to do that. there is no info in the internet at all...
im trying to create local backups at least and it doesnt work either
this is the code :

```
-(void)testCopyStoreToDocuments
{
    AppDelegate* appDelegate=(AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    [appDelegate.userDataDocument closeWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL closed)
     {
         if(closed)
         {
             @autoreleasepool {
                 NSFileCoordinator *fc = [[NSFileCoordinator alloc] initWithFilePresenter:nil];
                 NSString *sourceFile = [[[[LoadingManager localDocumentURL]URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"StoreContent"]path] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"persistentStore"];
                 NSURL *sourceURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:sourceFile];

                 [fc coordinateReadingItemAtURL:sourceURL options:NSFileCoordinatorReadingWithoutChanges error:nil byAccessor:^(NSURL *sourceURLtoUse) {
                     NSError *error = nil;
                     NSFileManager *fm = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
                     NSString *destinationFile = [[[LoadingManager localDocumentsDirectoryURL]path] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"persistentStore"];


                     //simply copy the file over
                     BOOL copySuccess = [fm copyItemAtPath:[sourceURLtoUse path]
                                                    toPath:destinationFile
                                                     error:&error];
                     if (copySuccess) {
                         NSLog(@" copied file successfully");
                     } else {
                         NSLog(@"Error copying item at path: %@\nTo path: %@\nError: %@", sourceFile, destinationFile, error);
                     }
                 }];
                 fc = nil;
             }

         }
     }];
}
-(void)testReplaceStore
{
    AppDelegate* appDelegate=(AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    [appDelegate.userDataDocument closeWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL closed)
     {
         if(closed)
         {
             NSFileCoordinator *fc = [[NSFileCoordinator alloc] initWithFilePresenter:nil];
             [fc coordinateWritingItemAtURL:[[[LoadingManager localDocumentURL]URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"StoreContent"]URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"persistentStore"] options:NSFileCoordinatorWritingForDeleting error:nil byAccessor:^(NSURL *sourceURLtoUse){
                 NSLog(@"%@",sourceURLtoUse);
                 NSError * error = nil;
                 NSLog(@"replacment: %hhd",[[NSFileManager defaultManager]replaceItemAtURL:sourceURLtoUse withItemAtURL:[[LoadingManager localDocumentsDirectoryURL]URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"persistentStore"] backupItemName:@"backUp" options:NSFileManagerItemReplacementUsingNewMetadataOnly resultingItemURL:nil error:&error]);
                 NSLog(@"%@",error);
             }];
             NSLog(@"stores: %@",appDelegate.userDataDocument.managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator.persistentStores);
             [appDelegate.userDataDocument saveToURL:appDelegate.userDataDocument.fileURL forSaveOperation:UIDocumentSaveForOverwriting completionHandler:^(BOOL saved)
              {
                  if(saved)
                  {
                      [appDelegate.userDataDocument openWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL opened)
                       {
                           if(opened)
                           {
                               NSLog(@"opened");
                           }

                       }];
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      NSLog(@"failed to save");
                      NSLog(@"stores: %@",appDelegate.userDataDocument.managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator.persistentStores);
                  }
              }];
         }
     }];
}
```

It Nslogs an error when replacing is called :

```
 replacment: 0
 Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=512 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 512.)" UserInfo=0x15d91540 {NSFileNewItemLocationKey=file:///var/mobile/Applications/85974C93-75FD-406A-B1BF-EDE7DFC25FE2/Documents/persistentStore, NSFileOriginalItemLocationKey=file:///var/mobile/Applications/85974C93-75FD-406A-B1BF-EDE7DFC25FE2/Documents/Data%20Document/StoreContent/persistentStore, NSUnderlyingError=0x15db0080 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 260.)",
```

Comment: It would help if you described what problem(s) you are encountering with the above code.

Comment: Is the file already there ?  Check if the target file it already there and delete it before the copy !!

Comment: BTW cocoa error 260 is
NSFileReadNoSuchFileError = 260,                        // Read error (no such file)
so perhaps the source file name is incorrect.  Run the app in the simulator and confirm these file paths are in fact correct.

Comment: Also if the Core Data store is shared in iCloud then you need to get the store fileURL from the store.  Core Data puts it in some directory of its own so UIManagedDocument reports the incorrect path.  Use the simulator to check the actual paths are correct.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested this code and it works fine.  Here is a sample app http://ossh.com.au/design-and-technology/software-development/sample-library-style-ios-core-data-app-with-icloud-integration/

You will get that error if the target file already exists.

```
/**  Copies file to iCloud container removing the target file if it already exists

 @param docURL  URL of UIManagedDocument whose store file is to be copied (its Core Data Store must not be shared in iCloud!
 */
- (void)copyFileToICloud:(NSURL*)docURL {
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSFileCoordinator *fc = [[NSFileCoordinator alloc] initWithFilePresenter:nil];
        NSURL *sourceURL = [[docURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"StoreContent"] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"persistentStore"];

        // Local directory - test
        //NSString *destinationFile = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"persistentStore_backup"];

        NSURL *destinationURL = [[[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:nil] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"persistentStore_backup"];


        FLOG(@" source file is %@", sourceURL);
        FLOG(@" target file is %@", destinationURL);

        NSError *cError;

        [fc coordinateWritingItemAtURL:destinationURL options:NSFileCoordinatorWritingForReplacing error:&cError byAccessor:^(NSURL *newURL) {
            NSError *error = nil;
            NSFileManager *fm = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];

            // Delete it if it already exists
            if ([fm fileExistsAtPath:[newURL path]]) {
                FLOG(@" target file exists");
                if (![fm removeItemAtURL:newURL error:&error]) {
                    FLOG(@" error unable to remove target file");
                    NSLog(@"Error removing item Error: %@, %@", error, error.userInfo);
                    return;
                } else {
                    FLOG(@" target file removed");
                }
            }

            //simply copy the file over
            BOOL copySuccess = [fm copyItemAtPath:[sourceURL path]
                                           toPath:[newURL path]
                                            error:&error];
            if (copySuccess) {
                NSLog(@" copied file successfully");
            } else {
                NSLog(@"Error copying items Error: %@, %@", error, error.userInfo);
            }
        }];

        if (cError) {
            FLOG(@" error is %@", cError);
        }

        fc = nil;
    }
}
```

EDIT:  A few additional things to remember:

- If you are using WAL mode (or the default Core Data mode for iOS7, OS X 10.9) then you have to copy the ~wal and ~shm files as well - better copy the entire StoreContent directory.
- To copy the files from iCloud you will have to do a metadata query to find the files and then check the download status, I think you will have to trigger the download and check the files have downloaded before you can copy them.